# Write/Read arrays in files android

Tags: java, android

for now i´ve got this two arrays that i want to save in a file

```
int var[][] = new int var[6][3]
int var_2[][] = new int var[7][5];
```

So whats the best way to write this into a file?

I´ve seen some examples like this

```
try {
  ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new
  FileOutputStream("data.dat"));
  objOut.writeObject(var_1);
  objOut.writeObject(var_2);
  objOut.close();
  }
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Am i doing this right? And if i am, how then do i read it right to my variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it right in concept, but there's room for improvement. First, you should use the Android logging facility (`android.util.Log`) rather than `e.printStackTrace()`. Also, if your minSdkLevel is 19 or more, I recommend that you use the [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new
    FileOutputStream("data.dat")))
{
    objOut.writeObject(var_1);
    objOut.writeObject(var_2);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not save data", e);
}
```

(`LOG_TAG` is just some `String` you define to identify your class's output.) If you can't use try-with-resources, I recommend using a `finally` clause to close the stream:

```
ObjectOutputStream objOut = null;
try {
    objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data.dat"))
    objOut.writeObject(var_1);
    objOut.writeObject(var_2);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not save data", e);
} finally {
    if (objOut != null) {
        try {
            objOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not close output file", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that the output stream gets closed even if an exception is thrown in the calls to `writeObject`.

To read the data back in, just open an `ObjectInputStream` to the same file and read the data *in the same order in which you wrote them*.